# Unable to cast object of type 'VB$StateMachine_4_GetAllFrontPageBanners' to type IEnumerable(Of FrontPageBanner)

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ado.net

I'm not really used to working with VB.NET, but i've come across an error where googling did not suffice. I've created this data access class, it has a method that makes use of `Yield` and vb.net's object initializer shortcut

```
Public Class FMACMarketingRepository
    Private cvConnection As SqlConnection
    Private cvCommand As SqlCommand
    Private cvReader As SqlDataReader

    Public Sub New(Role As InfotelLibrary.Data.DatabaseRole)
        cvConnection = New SqlConnection(InfotelLibrary.Data.ConnectionString(Role, InfotelLibrary.Data.DatabaseName.Mongoose))
    End Sub

    Public Iterator Function GetAllFrontPageBanners() As IEnumerable(Of FrontPageBanner)
        Using dbConnection As IDbConnection = cvConnection
            Using cmd As IDbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.CommandText = "sel_AllFmacFrontPageBanners"
                Using reader As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If reader Is Nothing Then
                        Yield Nothing
                    End If
                    While reader.Read()
                        Yield New FrontPageBanner() With
                        {
                            .Banner_Id = CType(reader("Banner_ID"), Integer),
                            .Geo_Id = CType(reader("Geo_ID"), Long),
                            .Title = CType(reader("Title"), String),
                            .Description = CType(reader("Description"), String),
                            .Link = CType(reader("Link"), String),
                            .Image = CType(reader("Image"), Byte()),
                            .SpecialOffer = CType(reader("Special_Offer"), Boolean)
                        }
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

There are 0 errors in Intellisense, it builds but when i run the webpage it get the error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'VB$StateMachine_4_GetAllFrontPageBanners' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InfotelData.Mongoose.Data.FrontPageBanner]'.

```
Line 7:  
Line 8:      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Line 9:          Dim banners As List(Of FrontPageBanner) = cvRepo.GetAllFrontPageBanners()
Line 10:         If banners.Count() > 0 Then
Line 11:             rptUploadedBanners.DataSource = banners
```

Debugging just gives the same error when it hits page_load.

I've the distinct feeling that user error is to blame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetAllFrontPageBanners` returns an `IEnumerable(Of FrontPageBanner)`***(*)*** and you're trying to store it inside a `List(Of FrontPageBanner)`. I'm surprised it doesn't give a compile time error (you're probably in [Option Strict Off](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) mode)

you need to make a List from the enumerable using [.ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example :

```
Dim banners As List(Of FrontBanner) = cvRepo.GetAllFrontPageBanners.ToList
```

<sub>***(*)*** *Internally an Iterator block transform the function into a generated "class-state-machine" (which implement IEnumerable(Of FrontBanner) in your case).

That's the odd name you got but you can (and should) consider it like the return type given in your source code.

More information about that [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx)*</sub>